# What's the meaning of "as for whether"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> If I do a master degree in Germany, I can learn how to research in the automobile industry, which is, of course, very competitive. **As for whether** it was the right decision, I’m pretty confident and I can’t change my mind now anyway because I borrowed money from my parents to pay for my tuition. I’m going to do my best to complete my course and I will go back to my country with new ideas that will help expand my opportunites.

What is the "as for whether"? I think it's one of phrases.

Comment: You should note that ["as **to** whether" is much more common than "as **for** whether"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+to+whether%2Cas+for+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20to%20whether%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20for%20whether%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @stangdon Ty for info. So the question is omitted here. Like, As to (the question) whether it was the right decision,.

Comment: Close!  It would be "As to the question **of** whether it was the right decision..."

Answer (score 3):

**As for whether...** can be paraphrased "*With respect to the question, whether* it was the right decision or the wrong decision..."